# Regular Expression needed for a Specific ID

Tags: regex, validation

I need to create a regular expression that matches an ID that has a specific format. The ID always begins with "OR" followed by 4 digits, then a dash, then another number that can be of any length. Examples of valid matches are:

```
OR1581-2
OR0057-101
OR0000-5312
OR3450-17371
```

Thanks!

Comment: Try this  `^(OR)\d{4}\-[0-9]+$`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `^OR\d{4}-\d+$`.

- The `^` matches the beginning of the string or line.
- `OR` is not a special sequence and will match only those two characters in order.
- `\d` matches any digit, and `{4}` is shorthand for listing the preceding group (the digit) exactly four times.
- `-` is not a special character and will match only the hyphen.
- `\d` matches any digit again, and the `+` requires the preceding group (the digit) to occur one or more times.
- `$` matches the end of the string or line.

Comment: That worked! Thank you! I really need to spend some time learning regexp sometime. Your answer was very helpful. http://fiddle.re/3fjk

Answer (score 0):

If you need to find match in string that contains such ID, but also other text, then use

```
\bOR\d{4}-\d+\b
```

However if you need to verify input if is in such format, so no other text around is allowed, then go with

```
^OR\d{4}-\d+$
```